# Getting error while downloading file from AzureStorageBlob

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Get-AzureStorageBlobContent : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the

"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type

"Deserialized.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to type

"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext".

- - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzureStorageBlobContent], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId :

CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageBlobContentCommand

Comment: Could it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command below to download file from blob storage to `C:\test\`, it works fine on my side.

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<StorageAccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "v7VSaxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5iQ=="
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "<container name>" -Blob "<blob name>" -Destination "C:\test\" -Context $context
```

[image]